# Search and replace hard returns in PHP

Tags: php, python, dictionary, escaping

I'm trying to take input from users submitting through a website (PHP) and put whatever they typed into a dictionary in a Python program.  The way I have it set up right now is that, for example, someone submits "John Smith" into the "Name" field on the website, hits submit, and their name gets saved in my Python dictionary as `'Name': 'John Smith'` for me to work with elsewhere. That part works fine.

Where I'm running into trouble is when users need to submit full paragraphs into some of the text fields.  My Python program is interpreting any hard returns / breaks between paragraphs as the end of the dictionary value, and then since the next bits of paragraph are not formatted in key:value pairs, the whole program crashes.

I was able to solve a similar problem when users submitted apostrophes (program again was reading this like the end of the value when it was not) by searching and replacing `"'"` with `"\\'"` in the PHP before it even touches my Python script so that it is already escaped correctly by the time it's put into the dictionary.

I can't figure out how to do the same thing with hard returns.  I've tried searching for `"\r"`, `"\\r"`, and tried to find `CR` and `LF` and everything else I could find about potential ways the hard returns might be used in the PHP, and tried replacing all of those with `"\\n\\n"` but none of those have worked.

I should note that, when I enter the full paragraphs into the dictionary by hand, using `\n\n`between lines, the program works just fine.

Considering pretty much EVERY user submission besides the Name field example that I used above will contain hard returns between paragraphs, it's a pretty huge problem that breaks the whole program.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

**Edited to add:**

As requested, I'm editing my question to add some code samples.

The process starts as the user enters some text into a text box on the website.  For example:

```
Product Description:  "This product blah blah blah blah.

Blah blah blah blah for a few paragraphs with hard returns in between them."
```

The content of this text box is saved into a PHP variable when the user hits Submit on the website, and the contents of that variable are emailed to me.  So for the above example, I would get an email formatted exactly as I typed it above, with the hard returns between paragraphs.

For text boxes that the user DOES NOT put a return into, for example `'Name' : 'John Smith'` as above, it's an easy matter of having that funneled directly into my Python dictionary as a key:value pair.

What I want to happen is to have my dictionary look like this:

```
dict = {
'Name': 'John Smith',
'Product Description': 'This product blah blah blah blah.\n\nBlah blah blah blah for a few paragraphs with hard returns in between them.'
}
```

What actually happens is this:

```
    dict = {
        'Name': 'John Smith',
        'Product Description': 'This product blah blah blah blah.'
        'Blah blah blah blah for a few paragraphs with hard returns in between them.'
}
```

Which obviously errors because "Blah blah blah blah for a few paragraphs with hard returns in between them." is not a key:value pair.

Earlier, I was having the same problem when the user would type an apostrophe into the text field.  For example:

```
Product Name: "John's Book of Recipes"
```

Would then show up as

```
'Product Name': 'John'
's Book of Recipes'
```

Which errored for the same reason - "'s Book of Recipes" is not a key:value pair.

I was able to solve that problem easily by putting this line in the PHP of the website:

```
$Product_Name = str_replace("'", "\\'", "$Product_Name");
```

Which replaces `"'"` with the properly escaped `"\\'`" before it ever gets emailed to me or sent to my Python dictionary.

That worked great.  Now my dictionary appears as:

```
dict = {
    'Name': 'John Smith'
    'Product Name': 'John\'s Book of Recipes'
 }
```

So now my question is, is there a way to search and replace for a specific character/code when the user has submitted text with a return between paragraphs?

I tried, similar to the above:

```
$Product_Description = str_replace("\r", "\\n\\n", "$Product_Description");
```

and the other attempts I mentioned before my edit, with the idea that I could search for whatever the PHP saves those hard returns as (evidently not "\r") and replace them with the "\n\n" that I know works in my Python code because that's how I've been hand-typing it so far.

Hopefully that's more clear.  If not, let me know and I will edit again.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample code.

Comment: I've added some code if you would like to take a look!  Thank you!

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you need types of line breaks/terminators. If I am wrong, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

**Some types of line terminations taken from WikiPedia**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline
LF:    Unix and Unix-like systems (Linux, macOS, FreeBSD, Multics, AIX, Xenix, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS, and others[1]

CR+LF: Microsoft Windows, DOS (MS-DOS, PC DOS, etc.), DEC TOPS-10, RT-11, CP/M, MP/M, Atari TOS, OS/2, Symbian OS, Palm OS, Amstrad CPC, and most other early non-Unix and non-IBM operating systems

CR:    Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, ZX Spectrum, TRS-80, Apple II family, Oberon, the classic Mac OS up to version 9, MIT Lisp Machine and OS-9

RS:    QNX pre-POSIX implementation

0x9B:  Atari 8-bit machines using ATASCII variant of ASCII (155 in decimal)

LF+CR: Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output.
The Unicode standard defines a number of characters that conforming applications should recognize as line terminators:[5]
 LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
 VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
 FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
 CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
 CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
 NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
 LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
 PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029
```